# PL/SQL create function with param for a check constraint

Tags: oracle, plsql

Given the [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/state.htm#TTSQL291):

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION [Owner.]FunctionName 
     [(arguments [IN|OUT|IN OUT][NOCOPY] DataType [DEFAULT expr][,...])]
     RETURN DataType [InvokerRightsClause] [DETERMINISTIC]
     {IS|AS}
```

I think my query is syntactically correct, but for some reason, I get these errors during compilation:

> Error(6,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(8,34): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION aCombinationMismatches(p_column1 IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN Number
IS
duplicate_count NUMBER(4,0);
BEGIN
    select count(*) into duplicate_count
    from schema1.tableA a
    inner join schema1.tableB b
    on a.b_id = b.id and a.column1 = p_column1
    group by a.b_id, a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2, b.column3;
    return duplicate_count;
END;
```

Anyone see anything wrong with my query above?

Also I'd like to how to set this UDF up to be used to create a `CHECK` constraint. How exactly do I specify the param: `p_param1` to the function assuming this is the value of a field `column1` in a row that a user is trying to insert? I just don't want the user to insert a record into `tableA` that consists of duplicate combinations of fields across tables: `tableA` and `tableB`.

---

Note: The tables `tableA` and `tableB` do exist - a `select` query like below indicates it. So the error above is rather confusing to me, I must add. (*All table and column names in the two queries were found/replaced with dummy values.*)

```
select count(*)
from schema1.tableA a
inner join schema1.tableB b
on a.b_id = b.id
group by a.b_id, a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2, b.column3;
```

Output:

> ### Count(*)

Comment: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` - this simply means that `tableA` or `tableB` does not exist.

Comment: @krokodilko I added a note to indicate that the tables do exist. Perhaps the first error has something to do with it?

Comment: The compiler thinks the tables don't exist, you think they do. No offence but my money's on the compiler. Probably it's a typo or perhaps the tables are named using double-quotes and mixed case. Simplest thing is for you to post the output of the "simple select query".

Comment: @APC I just added the sample `select` query I used to confirm that the tables exist. FWIW, all table and column names in the two queries were found/replaced with dummy values.

Comment: It doesnt matter whether they do exist or not. The query has a group by clause, so it can return many rows as a result. You are trying to assing multiple results (multiple counts - multiple numbers) to a scalar variable, so it will fail anyway.

Comment: Are tables in your schema or not? Query `user_tables` data  dictionary view. Show the result.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I think I see the problem. I tried to create the function without mentioning the owner. The tables, however, are in the schema: `schema1`. Now that I try to create my function in this schema I see that I don't have the privileges. My bad! Can you add your comment as the answer anyway so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you already know that you have problem with priviliges. I wanted to add that you won't be able to create CHECK constraint basing on your function. According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52204):

- The condition of a check constraint can refer to any column in the table, but **it cannot refer to columns of other tables.**
- Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following constructs:

  - **Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions**
  - Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE, LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE, SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and USERENV)
  - **Calls to user-defined functions**

So to achieve what you want, you would have to define some triggers, or make use of some combination of MATERIALIZED VIEW and CHECK constraint. See for example this [discussion on Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:4233459000346171405)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have access to TableA and TableB through a Role. This means that you can query the table, but you cannot create a procedure that reads or writes that table. In order to compile your procedure you should at least grant select on the table to your user.

In the link below you'll find more info

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319